# How to test OTP verification with appium

Tags: android, macos, appium

How to test OTP verification with Appium.
I want to do OTP verification by appium can any one help me?.

Comment: what you tried so far ?

Comment: Hi Raj, did you get any solution for your problem? If so, please post it here.

Answer (score 2):

Using Appium you can automate and control your app but there are certain limitations You need to understand the process of generating OTP. Whenever you do some transaction OTP will get generated and send to your Mobile device. So you can automate the process to perform such transaction. But after that to enter OTP which is in your Inbox you need to open your Inbox, Find the Message, Extract the OTP, Enter it. This is very complex process to automate using Appium.

I think the better alternative is to Set one fix OTP number for testing purpose instead of requesting OTP Real time.

Comment: My suggestion is to do OTP Varification part Manually. And it must work if you tested it well with fake OTP's. an automated testing script which can handle all possible situations by itself without manual intervention is good. But by doing so, we will end up in developing another software which is again very difficult to design, develop and maintain.

Answer (score 1):

You can switch between apps in Android. On sending OTP using your app, switch to android default message app and read OTP and then switch back to your test app.

```
driver.startActivity(AppPackageName, AppActivityName);
```

The above call can be used to switch between different app. Replace AppPackageName and AppActivityName with your test app package name / activity name and android default message app name respectively.

Answer (score 1):

You can automate OTP validation from Appium in two ways.

1. By opening messages application in android and reading OTP from there.
2. By opening notifications and read OTP.

To open messages application we need to open the app using below code:

```
driver.startActivity(AppPackageName, AppActivityName);
```

To Read OTP from notification pane we can open notification pane using below code:

```
driver.openNotifications()
```

Now you can inspect OTP text element and read the text. For example, if your OTP text is

> Your OTP is 3357

You will get otp as below:

```
string otp = driver.findElementByXpath("//*[contains(@text,"Your OTP is")]").getText().split(" is")[1]
```

Above code will return OTP into the string variable. Now you can use below code to come back to the application.

```
driver.navigate().back();
```

This solution is for Android only.

Answer (score 0):

yes, i think you are right but, i need to login before use the app and login page have a OTP verification thats why i need to check OTP.
i can build a app with out OTP for testing but can not do every time because i have to test production build which are going to far user and in this build i can not hide OTP verification.

Answer (score 0):

For OTP verification you can use Android messenger. Download android messenger apk, create test scrips to launch and read message using this app.

I don't know how to do for iOS, Can any one suggest here how to do for iOS based application.

Thanks,
Sadik